# How to use keyup function for multiple forms input

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, forms, input

I have multiple forms on my page with the same input.
I'd like to multiple some value from inputs.
Now my code working only for first form inputs.

```
 $("#quantity").each(function () {
            var $final_price = $('#final_price');
            $("#quantity").on('keyup', function (e) {
                var quantity = parseFloat($(this).val());
                var product_price = parseFloat($("input[name='product_price']").val(), 10);
                $final_price.val(quantity * product_price);
            });
        });
```

EDIT, working code:

```
    $(".ilosc").on('keyup', function (e) {
        var quantity = parseFloat($(this).val());
        var product_price = parseFloat($("input[name='product_price']").val(), 2);
        var final_price_input= $(this).closest("form").find(".final-price-rental-value");
        var final_price_value = (quantity * product_price).toFixed(2);
        var final_price_input_value = final_price_input.val(final_price_value);
    });
```

Comment: Id attribute must be unique. If it is repeated, only the first element will be remembered by DOM. Try unique Ids OR class attributes.

Comment: Almost working correctly. Now when I change value in second form in quantity input, it multiple final price in first form finaly price

Comment: Same issue `$('#final_price')` can only refer to a single input.  You need to use relative DOM navigation to find the correct input; without your HTML we can only speculate:  `$(this).closest("form").find(".final_price").val(...`

Comment: that's the point

Answer (score 2):

Your HTML should be

```
<input type="number" name="quantity" class="quantity" required="required">
```

Your Javascript should be

```
$(".quantity").on('keyup', function (e) {
    var quantity = parseFloat($(this).val());
    var product_price = parseFloat($("input[name='product_price']").val(), 10);
    $final_price.val(quantity * product_price);
});
```

Comment: Almost working correctly.
Now when I change value in second form in quantity input, it multiple final price in first form finaly price

Comment: You need to keep the index that its either first or 2nd or 3rd and based on that final price will be calculated

Answer (score 0):

Your code only works on the first form because you are targeting an id, i.e. `#quantity`, and you [can only have one id per page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id).

What you need to do is use classes, e.g.:

```js
$('.quantity').each(function(index, value) {
  var $input = $(value);
  console.log($input.val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form>
  <input type="text" class="quantity" value="232" />
</form>

<form>
  <input type="text" class="quantity" value="765" />
</form>

<form>
  <input type="text" class="quantity" value="987" />
</form>
```